# Can I use an if statement around a cursor or a while loop with fetch

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I had an issue with solving this problem I was given.

> If n < 0, display an error message “Invalid number!”.
>
> If n = 0, display all rows (Sex, Rank, Given_Name, and
>   Number_of_Occurrences) in the tbl_baby_name table.  Sort your output
>   in ascending order by sex, and then rank.
>
> If n > 0, display all rows (Sex, Rank, Given_Name,  and
>   Number_of_Occurrences) having rank  ≤ n in the tbl_baby_name table. 
>   Sort your output in ascending order by sex, and then rank.

How can I display only the rank of the babies that are less than the number the user inputted. I have the output of all the babies but I only wanted the ones with rank less then what the user at entered.

Whenever I try and put an if statement around the cursor it gives me an error. It also won't let me add a while loop around the fetch statement.

Can someone please help!

```
ACCEPT p_1 PROMPT 'Enter  a number :'
DECLARE
        v_n                    NUMBER := &p_1;
        v_baby_rank            TBL_BABY_NAME.RANK%TYPE;
        v_baby_sex             VARCHAR(80);
        v_baby_name            TBL_BABY_NAME.GIVEN_NAME%TYPE;
        v_baby_numoc           TBL_BABY_NAME.NUMBER_OF_OCCURRENCES%TYPE;

    CURSOR c_baby IS
            SELECT         rank, CASE sex WHEN 'M' THEN 'Male' ELSE 'Female' END, GIVEN_NAME, NUMBER_OF_OCCURRENCES
            FROM           TBL_BABY_NAME
            ORDER BY       sex,rank;
BEGIN
    if v_n < 0 Then 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid Number');
    Else
        OPEN c_baby;
        FETCH c_baby 
        INTO v_baby_rank, v_baby_sex, v_baby_name, v_baby_numoc;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( RPAD('Sex',10) || RPAD('Rank',10) || RPAD('Given Name',15) || ('Number of Occurrences') );
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('===========================================================');
        while c_baby%FOUND loop
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RPAD(v_baby_sex, 10) || RPAD(v_baby_rank,10) || RPAD(v_baby_name,30) || v_baby_numoc);
            FETCH c_baby 
            INTO v_baby_rank, v_baby_sex, v_baby_name, v_baby_numoc;
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE c_baby;
    END IF;
END;
```

[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vx2e9.png)

Comment: For which database server. You have three listed here and they all use different syntax.

Comment: For oracle sql developer. My bad.

Comment: " it gives me an error"  - which is?

Comment: It just won't let me put an if statment around the cursor. Won't execute

Comment: A few questions: why are there two FETCH statements? They seem to do the same thing. Could you consider using some method to load the records in bulk? What is the purpose of the input parameter? I don't see it mentioned anywhere in your code other than the first IF statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "It just won't let me put an if statment around the cursor. Won't execute"

The simplest way of meeting the requirement would be this:

```
    while c_baby%FOUND loop
        if  v_n = 0 
        or  c_baby.rank < v_n 
        then
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RPAD(v_baby_sex, 10) || RPAD(v_baby_rank,10) || RPAD(v_baby_name,30) || v_baby_numoc);
        end if;
        FETCH c_baby
```

It selects all the records but only displays the ones which matches teh input criterion.

If performance is a concern - not for your homework but it will matter in real life - then you might want to select a filtered result set instead of selecting everything and discarding the unwanted rows. In this scenario you would use a cursor variable instead:

```
.....
    c_baby sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
    if v_n < 0 Then 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid Number');
    Elsif v_n > 0 Then 
        OPEN c_baby for
            SELECT         rank, CASE sex WHEN 'M' THEN 'Male' ELSE 'Female' END, GIVEN_NAME, NUMBER_OF_OCCURRENCES
            FROM           TBL_BABY_NAME
            where rank < v_n
            ORDER BY       sex,rank;
    Else 
        OPEN c_baby for
            SELECT         rank, CASE sex WHEN 'M' THEN 'Male' ELSE 'Female' END, GIVEN_NAME, NUMBER_OF_OCCURRENCES
            FROM           TBL_BABY_NAME
            ORDER BY       sex,rank;
    end if;
    FETCH c_baby 
    INTO .... -- the rest of your posted code
```

Using a cursor variable allows us to inject a different result set into a standard set of processing. It is possible to avoid the duplicated code in the SELECT by using dynamic SQL, but that probably exceeds the brief.